# How to get English month name from date in Russian Excel?

Tags: excel, datetime, localization, internationalization, locale

I am unable to get month name in Excel.

Neither `=TEXT(...;"mmmm")` not doesn't work.

I found, only Russian M's are working and giving Russian month name, despite of language settings

[image]

Latin M's give nothing.

Are there any other settings to force month name language?

**UPDATE**

Setting date format nationality didn't help:

[image]

Comment: Try this: `=TEXT(B2;"[$-eng-us]MMMM")`

Comment: or this `=TEXT(B2;"[$-409]MMMM")`

Comment: I like this solution! Do you know if there's a list of approved locales? Using `"[$-fra-fr]MMMM"` brings up Arabic on mine!

Comment: @YiminRong which Arabic Kuwait, Jordan, Lebanon...

Comment: [Full List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx)

Comment: @ScottCraner but the M's should be Russian. It doesn't work with English.

Comment: @ScottCraner `,` insted of `;`

Comment: @meni181818 only if your local settings use that.  Some local settings use ';' instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for additional details. It appears to be a long standing issue with MS Office. See [How to prevent Excel to use the OS regional settings for date patterns in formulas](https://superuser.com/questions/730371/how-to-prevent-excel-to-use-the-os-regional-settings-for-date-patterns-in-formul) for a related issue and some partial solutions.

In particular, hardcoding using `CHOOSE` might be your way to go:

`=CHOOSE(MONTH(B2);"Jan";"Feb";"Mar";"Apr";"May";"Jun";"Jul";"Aug";"Sep";"Oct";"Nov";"Dec")`

Also see Scott Craner's comment regarding `=TEXT(B2;"[$-0409]MMMM")` which looks like a quick fix. But note that the `MMMM` has to be in your locale, so the spreadsheet might not be portable. The `CHOOSE` option would be better in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix this problem. First you need to go to Excel options and click "Advanced". After that, you need to scroll down to the bottom of this page and edit the "Edit Custom Lists..." button located in the "General" tab. [Image for first step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpmX1.png)

Finally, you should add your own lists by clicking NEW LIST.
[Image for final steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmDcV.png)

January
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
September
October
November
December