# Excel Formula works in Dublin but not in Finland or Denmark

Tags: date, text, excel-formula

I hope you can help I have an Excel formula `=TEXT('Junk Sheet'!A2,"MM/DD/YYYY")` The issue I am facing is that I am getting different results for this formula from different countries

In screen shot 1 you can see the result from Ireland

In screen shot 2 you can see the result from Denmark

In screen shot 3 you can see the result from Finland

In order for another database to accept this information I need the formula to return the result that Ireland produces. Other countries highlighting the column then using custom formatting date MM/DD/YYYY is not an option as this entire sheet needs to remain in TEXT format for the other database to accept and this sheet is also hidden and locked to prevent human intervention in data.

I need the other countries to return the same result as Ireland, without human intervention, can my formula be manipulated or some VBA be incorporated or how can i prevent the different results in different countries happening with this formula?

As always any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Screen Shot 1

[image]

Screen Shot 2

[image]

Screen Shot 3

[image]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43525469/how-to-get-english-month-name-from-date-in-russian-excel

Comment: What is the value of A2, or whatever cell is feeding into the Text() function?

Comment: Hi assylias. Thank you for taking the time to respond I looked at your link and tried `=TEXT(B2;"[$-eng-us]MM/DD/YYYY")` but still it did not work. Is there another solution?

Comment: Hi Teylyn. Than you for taking the time to respond. The value in A2 is numeric 42871 which is today's date 05/16/2017 but the other database that this Excel sheet will feed will not accept 42871. The date needs to be MM/DD/YYYY so that is why i put the numeric 42871 into my Junk sheet and then transform to 05/16/2017 with my formula `=TEXT('Junk Sheet'!A2,"MM/DD/YYYY")` This also keeps 05/16/2017 as text. The problem is i think TEXT is not spelled the same in different countries and the formula fails. I am looking for a way around this.

Comment: @PhilipConnell Did you notice that in your second last comment you have one formula with a semicolon and in your last comment a formula that uses a comma separating the parameters? Depending on your regional settings, your formulas need either a comma or a semicolon. So try the formula that "did not work" with a comma?

Answer (score 1):

Dates are stored as numeric values in Excel and then formatted according to the regional settings to appear like the observer in that country would want to see them.

If A2 holds a real date value then you can just use a reference to A2 like this

=A2

and use the "short date" format in Excel, which will format the data according to the regional settings of the user who opens the workbook.

If you use the Text function with a fixed formatting string, the formatting string letters may not be the same in the different locales. In fact, the Text function has specific switches to apply country specific settings to the formatting string.

`=TEXT(A1,"[$-409]mmmm, yyyy")`

The 409 is the switch for US English. Other countries can be looked up on the internet, for example here: https://excelribbon.tips.net/T011782_Specifying_a_Language_for_the_TEXT_Function.html

So, the Text() function will NOT work across different locales.

That's why there is such a thing as the "short date format", which automatically takes the locale into account.

If your workbooks are used in different locales with different settings and languages, don't use the Text() function to format dates with formatting strings that only make sense for the English language.

Use the short date format instead, because it can handle the language differences.

Edit: see [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1064577/excel-text-function-specifying-language-lcid). Even with the lcid, you can't use the TEXT() function across different locales, because the formatting string will need to use the letters for day, month, year of the locale where the file is opened. So in the Danish version of the file you would need to use the Danish letters for day, month, year, and in the Finnish version you would need to use the Finnish characters for day, month, year, which are most likely not "d", "m" or "y". Since the formatting string is a text, it will not be adjusted to the locale when the file is opened in another language version of Excel.

Comment: Hi Teylyn. thank you again for the information it was helpful. but if I format the column for Short Date then will I lose the TEXT formatting? This will mean the other database will reject the Excel file. I am afraid I cant just =A2 either as A2 is numeric and I need the 05/16/2017 format as text

Comment: I added a link to a similar question and some more explanation why the Text() function won't work for your scenario.